# PyQt- CheckedListBox?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I am developing a GUI with PyQt and want to know if there is something like the "CheckedListBox" (from VB.Net) for PyQt.
If not, are there any alternative solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `QListWidget`for that. You just have to make the items checkable by using the item flag `Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable`:

```
class CheckList(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, strings, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        for text in strings:
            item = QListWidgetItem(text)
            item.setFlags(item.flags() | Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
            item.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
            self.addItem(item)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = CheckList(["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4", "item 5"])
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```